# Error in Conditional Tool of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, conditional

I am trying to extract stream raster from a flow accumulation raster using Conditional Tool in Spatial Analyst.

Here's my input:

1. Input Raster: FLOWACC.tif
2. Expression: Value >= 3.5
3. True Raster: 1
4. Output raster: Stream.tif

Error gives me invalid expression. Basically my objective is to isolate all values >=3.5 and consider them as stream raster.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: the expression should be : "Value" >=3.5, not Value >=3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the raster calculator you must use this:

```
stream = con([FLOWACC] > 3.5, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this from the python window

```
#import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = #path to workspace
input_raster = #path to input raster
r = arcpy.Raster(input_raster)
output_raster = #path to output raster
temp_r = arcpy.sa.Con(r>=3.5,1)
temp_r.save(output_raster)
```

Refer to [the Con Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) documentation for more information.

Comment: `Con` is unnecessary: the result of the comparison `r>=3.5` is already what is needed.  In some applications, `SetNull` needs to be applied to the negation of the criterion so that cells which do not meet it are replaced with NoData--but `Con` is still superfluous.

Answer (score -3):

You might have to convert your raster to integer first using the raster calculator:

Formula:

```
int(raster*10)
```

Then query with value >= 35

Comment: Could you please describe the purpose of `int(raster*10)`?

Comment: Times 10 doesn't help here

Comment: It seems that using SQL icon interface, instead of typing into expression box might help